# robots.txt from database for asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, iis

I have a custom made CMS for a website, and would like to output the `robots.txt` file based on contents in a database, rather than having to actually modify the file system.

I know that usually IIS would cache such a file as static content, and as long as it has not changed it would not have to load it each time from disk.

I was thinking about storing the contents of what should be in the `robots.txt` in memory (static string or in a singleton), and then an `HttpHandler` would output the contents.

Is this a good approach?  Is there a better way?  I would like to ideally mimic as much the IIS static file caching.

Answer (score 0):

I think you point the right way. Check [this](http://www.kleenecode.net/2012/08/16/dynamic-robots-txt-with-asp-net-in-iis7/).

You have all the control over the response code so just handle that based on an internal date from your database. You can set a new ETag each time the file "changes".

```
Response.AddHeader("ETag","\"" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "\"");
```

This will give all the control you'll need over the cache.